# General failure building bootstrapper

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, setup-project, setup-deployment, bootstrapper

while doing the build of my dontnet 4.0 project setup i'm getting following errors

```
An error occurred generating a bootstrapper: Unable to finish updating resource for E:\project\Setup\Debug\setup.exe with error 8007006E    E:project\Setup\Setup.vdproj    Setup

General failure building bootstrapper   E:\project\Setup\Setup.vdproj   Setup

Unrecoverable build error   E:\project\\Setup\Setup.vdproj Setup
```

I am using dotnet framework 4 and MSVS 2010.

Comment: ya i tried with rebuild all.. but it not works getting same error

Comment: Rebuild all worked for me

Comment: Rebuild all worked for me too

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This happens because The .NET framework version required by the setup project is different than the .NET framework version targeted by the application.

To change verify this:

1. In Solution Explorer, click the Setup project.
2. On the View menu, point to Editor, and then click **Launch Conditions**.
3. Click .NET Framework.
4. In the Properties window, change the Version property to the version of the .NET    Framework that you want the Setup project to check for and install.

And also you need to Make sure that the Setup.exe program also checks for and installs the correct version of the .NET Framework.

Right click on the **setup project  -> Properties -> Prerequisites ->** Select the correct ones.

Comment: Thanks for the response i tried with this but still getting same error.

Comment: I get this error intermittently, if I hit 'F6' enough times it will compile.  This seems to happen when a solution grows to a moderate size (about 15 projects in it)

Comment: I found I had to delete the contents of my `\bin\debug` folder as it contained a problematic `app.publish` folder from one of the previous failed builds. After that, and updating the prerequisites, the publish succeeded.

Comment: Cleaning the solution worked for me, thanks a lot @EvanWondrasek

Comment: For me, I changed it down a version, then back up a version, hit save all, and then right clicked the setup project and clicked "rebuild". Then it started working.

Answer (score 15):

When I turn McAfee real-time scan off, it works.  I spent 2 hours on figuring this out :(

Comment: +1 When I disabled my Kaspersky Anti Virus it started working.

Comment: Same issue with McAfee +1 for your help ;)

Comment: Love it, I would never find it by myself.

Comment: Thank You. I had also same issue because of Net protector anti virus. Its fixed by disabling.

Comment: Had to disable Windows 10's Windows Defender Real-time protection, then it worked.

Comment: Thank you , how did you find this way? I turned off windows deffender virus protection and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

I googled a lot on this issue after trying all i just disabled my antivirus(NPAV) and this issue was solved.

Answer (score 3):

turning off mcafee real time scanning worked for me as well on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 2):

Here is yet another solution, this one is unlike the rest...

We recently added NTFS replication to our build tree root to provide some additional data redundancy and to begin to sync our old build machine with the new server. The NTFS replication caused some projects to fail with the exact same three error reported, and yet other projects work just fine. Set the replication on only run at night and the problem stopped occurring...

K

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when I changed targeted framework to 4.0 but neglected to change prerequisits for click once from 3.5 to 4.0 as well.
Fixing prerequisits resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of disabling the Anti-Virus, I would suggest to just create an exclusion for your Solution Folder. See documentation if you are using Windows Defender. [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028485/windows-10-add-an-exclusion-to-windows-defender-antivirus)

Answer (score 1):

I've just had this same error and then realised Dropbox was running. I closed Dropbox and then the build completed successfully.

Comment: Disabling Dropbox solved this error for me, too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you qwerty13579! How stupid of me, the solution is obvious. I have tried all sorts of things suggested over the internet, and even with the most recent version of VS Community 2017 (15.9.9), the bootstrapper failure pops up erratically, but with increasing frequency, to the point of frustration this past week. The principle: It doesn't succeed reliably, so it also doesn't FAIL reliably. The solution: Click the Publish Now button and watch the output panel. When it's that clear that it's failing, click the Publish Now button again immediately. Keep at it until it succeeds! Each round only takes a couple of seconds, much less time that it takes to re-build, take down anti-virus, and all that fancy stuff.

In my case, I traced the problem to an incorrectly dated setup.exe file in the bin\Release\app.publish folder of my application. When it fails, Publish Now creates an setup.exe that's two years earlier than the current day. When it succeeds, the setup.exe file is correctly dated.

Answer (score 0):

my target program was open
just close the program and it's fixed

Answer (score -1):

Got the same problem. I disabled Windows Defender real-time protection and it worked. I also added the folder where the solution is saved in exclusions for Defender, and that allowed me to publish as well.

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50244415/2227743).