# An error occurred generating a bootstrapper

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

I have a VS 2010 project that I've been having no end of trouble getting to build since my corporate overlords moved me to Windows 7 (finally).

I persistently get this error:

```
An error occurred generating a bootstrapper: Unable to finish updating resource for X:\Foo\Bar\Debug\setup.exe with error 8007006E
```

Sometimes doing a clean and then building again works. Sometimes closing the project and reopening works. The last time I could only get it to build by cleaning out my temp folder. Does anybody have any idea what's going on here and how to permanently fix it?

Usually trying to build again leads to a whole slew of errors complaining about how it can't compile this and that, followed by can't find this dll (presumably because it failed to build it).

I have a feeling the problem is rooted in the fact that `My Documents` is now on a network share.

**Update**: Moving everything off of my network share onto my local hard drive does solve the problem. It seems to build just fine from there, so it's definitely related to the network share. I don't want to keep the project on my local hard drive however because the network share is automatically backed up.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891083/general-failure-building-bootstrapper

Comment: @JoshGreifer: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Have you already tried sharing in read-only?

Comment: My problem solved after I stopped all dropbox tasks on the background. The project is on a dropbox folder, I just turn them on after publishing

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem in VS 2022 with my projects kept in a corporate dropbox folder.
I was able to get this to work by changing the Build Output Path to a non dropbox folder, specifically C:\temp\Visual Studio Build\project name\

It's really annoying that it behaves this way, but it could be worse.