# While Creating setup showing Error in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am working on visual studio 2010. I am trying to Rebuild my setup project but I am getting these 3 error(s):

1: `An error occurred generating a bootstrapper: Unable to finish updating resource for C:\Users\IBS Support\Desktop\Evalet Without Printer & Stored Procedrure\1\EVallet-Desktop\EvaletSetup\Debug\setup.exe with error 80070005`

2: `General failure building bootstrapper`

3: `Unrecoverable build error`

I am using MS Visual Studio 2010, version 10.0.30319.1 
(.Net FrameWork Version 4.5.50709)

Answer (score 3):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891083/general-failure-building-bootstrapper) should help you.

Quote from the post:

> This happens because The .NET framework version required by the setup project is different than the .NET framework version targeted by the application.
>   To verify this:
>
> 1. In `Solution Explorer`, select the setup project.
> 2. On the `View` menu, point to `Editor`, and then click `Launch Conditions`. Click `.NET
>      Framework`.
> 3. In the `Properties` window, change the `Version` property to the version of the .NET Framework that you want the setup project to check for and install.

Hope this helps?

Comment: sir i already did this things ..i given .NET Framework 4 Client Profile

Comment: @user2648161 Did you try a rebuild and a rebuild all? Also - did you follow all the suggestions on the suggested post? (They were also using .Net4.0).

Comment: i tryed to rebuild..where is the option to rebuild all?

Comment: @user2648161 Follow this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342107/how-to-rebuild-all

Comment: sir,,in mine i am not able to see batch build solution option